# How to fix this output

Tags: java

So the problem is am trying to input 100000 no.'s but  i am getting, 
output = 0
and also i am not able to paste all 100000 no. in cmd

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class practise{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        long num = 1, numb = 1;
        long arr[] = new long[100000];

        for(int i = 0; i < 100000 ; i++){
            arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        for(int j = 0 ; j < 10000 ; j++){
            if(arr[j] == 0){
               num = num * numb;
               numb++ ;            
            }
        }
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

Comment: A lot of inputs, how you end execute this ?

Comment: The code seems to have inexplicable features. For example, why process only the first 10,000 of the 100,000 inputs?  Why only process numbers less than 10,000? And the value of the input number does not affect the output value.

Comment: If there are N numbers < 10000 you should get N! as result. This might overflow even a long. Happy debugging by the way. It seems you do not need the array, is it not?

Comment: I suggest you start with 5 inputs to debug your code. If you really want 100000 numbers you can generate them randomly instead of reading from the console.

Comment: Make your program file enable and read 100000 numbers from the file. Debug your code to find out whats wrong.

Comment: If the output is zero, the only explanations are (1) overflow, (2) the first 10,000 input numbers all exceed 10,000.

Comment: @another-dave N! is the result, so counting the factors 2, and there should at least be N/2 even factors (in fact a factor 8 would give 3 factors 2), for N >= 128 (even ~100) the product is 0.

Comment: @ManLaw no inputs is 0

Comment: hey guys I did a mistake in my code now I've corrected it please reconsider reading it

Comment: @Ivar - at no point is any input number used in the multiplication.  The product starts at 1 and is multiplied by 1, 2, 3, ... (possibly skipping terms based on input, but not multiplying by the input)

Comment: @VaibhavBisht  - the new code never does any multiplication except for when there zeroes in the input array.  If the input array contains no zeroes then the output will be 1.

Comment: @another-dave Good call. Overlooked that.

Comment: @VaibhavBisht - why don't you explain what  you're trying to do?  The code does not seem to make sense taken as a whole, so it's difficult to say what the 'fix' is.  For example, some of it is almost computing N!, but if that is the intent, the input array seems pointless.

Answer (score 0):

If there are N numbers == 0 you should get N! as result. This might overflow even a long (64 bits). Happy debugging by the way. It seems you do not need the array, is it not?

N! is the result, so counting the factors 2, and there should at least be N/2 even factors (in fact a factor 8 would give 3 factors 2), for N >= 128 (even ~100) the product is 0.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    long result = 1L;
    int num = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100_000 ; i++){
        int numb = scan.nextInt();
        if (numb == 0) {
            result *= num;
            ++num;
            if (result == 0L) {
                System.out.println("Stopping at i = " + i + ", num = " + num);
                break; // result would stay 0.
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

One could use a BigInteger, but I think the task is intended to overflow ... to 0.
And maybe to find you do not need to read all numbers, neither store them in an array.

Comment: hey am sorry i did a mistake in the code so please reconsider reading it

Comment: I grasp only the condition which numbers are counted was changed.

Comment: hey but the thing is the array is necessary because I have to compare it with other array so how am gonna do it with the array

Comment: Okay, but the finally calculated 0 at least should be clear now.

Comment: hey u said that N! will be the result but since the input is both 0's and other no. the input will not be N! ;

Comment: In the original `num = num * numb; numb++;` no array value is assigned. So in the loop happens: `num = 1*1; num = 1*2; num = (1*2)*3; num = (1*2*3)*4; ...`. Perhaps you reduced the code a bit too much for the question.

Comment: And 4! has 3 least significant bits 0, 8! has 7 bits 0, 16! has 15 bits 0 so at one time num is set to 64 bits 0 = 0.